# ASP.NET MVC, Remove [Required] on complex properties types types

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation, complextype

I would like to make the sub properties of a complex type required ONLY in certain circunstancies. for this purpose i'm using FoolProof lib.

For instance, To register a work week schedule.
I do have a POCO complex class for storing timespans like this:

```
[ComplexType]
class workDay{

    [Required]
    public TimeSpan start { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public TimeSpan end { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public TimeSpan interval { get; set; }

}
```

the relevant part of the week POCO class is:

```
[ComplexType]
class Week{

    [Required]
    public bool monday { get; set; }
    [RequiredIfTrue("monday")]
    public workDay monday_timespan  {get;set;}

    [Required]
    public bool tuesday { get; set; }
    [RequiredIfTrue("tuesday")]
    public workDay tuesday_timespan {get;set;}

    // ...

    [Required]
    public bool sundat { get; set; }
    [RequiredIfTrue("sunday")]
    public workDay sunday_timespan {get;set;}
}
```

As you can see, the WorkDay class is only required to be filled in if the correspondent day is true.

However the validation always require all timespans to be filled. Is somehow possible to disable a required parameter inside a sub complextype parameter based on the Week POCO class?

Comment: Does this validation only need to occur server-side?

Comment: I don't think `RequiredIf` in `FoolProof ` works for complex models and also annotation follows for nearest one which in your case means `workDay` annotations. try to add `workDay` properties to your `Week` class and then handle details in model binding.

Comment: `[RequiredIf("tuesday")]` makes no sense. The format is `[RequiredIf("someOtherProperty", "ValueOfOtherProperty")]` Perhaps you meant `[RequiredIfTrue("tuesday")]`?

Comment: But in any case, you cannot apply validation attributes to complex properties (only to value types and `string`)

Comment: you're right. I just correct it @StephenMuecke

Comment: You need to create a view model to represent what you want in the view. Is your intention to generate a table, one row for each day of the week and have a checkbox, and if checked, you want all 3 properties of `workDay` to be required (and if its not checked, then they can be blank)?

Comment: exactly @StephenMuecke

Comment: No, the validation don't need to occur on server site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot apply validation attributes to complex properties and get client side validation because you do not (and cannot) create a form control for a complex object (only properties of the object). You need to create a view model to represent what you want to display in the view (note the nullable properties)

```
public class DayScheduleVM
{
    public bool IsRequired { get; set; } // this will be used for conditional validation
    [RequiredIf("IsRequired", ErrorMessage = "Please enter the start time")]
    public TimeSpan? StartTime { get; set; }
    [RequiredIf("IsRequired", ErrorMessage = "Please enter the end time")]
    public TimeSpan? EndTime { get; set; }
    [RequiredIf("IsRequired", ErrorMessage = "Please enter the interval")]
    public TimeSpan? Interval { get; set; }
}
public WeekScheduleVM
{
    public DayScheduleVM Sunday { get; set; }
    public DayScheduleVM Monday { get; set; }
    ....
}
```

and in the view

```
@model WeekScheduleVM
....
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <table>
        ....
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Sunday)</td>
                <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => Sunday.IsRequired)</td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Sunday.StartTime)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => Sunday.StartTime)
                </td>
                .... // ditto for EndTime and Interval
            </tr>
            <tr>
                .... // ditto for Monday,Tuesday etc
            </tr>
```

Then if the check box is checked, you will get a client (and server side) error it the associated `StartTime`, `EndTime` and `Interval` properties are not filled in (its not clear what `Interval` is for - the name suggests its a calculated value based on `StartTime` and `EndTime` so it may not be required in the view)

You can simplify this further and significantly reduce the amount of code in the view by adding a `DayOfWeek` enum property to `DayScheduleVM`

```
public DayOfWeek Day { get; set; }
```

so that in your GET method, you can use

```
List<DayScheduleVM> model = new List<DayScheduleVM>();
foreach (var day in Enum.GetValues(typeof(DayOfWeek)))
{
    days.Add(new DayScheduleVM { Day = (DayOfWeek)day });
}
return View(model);
```

and in the view

```
@model List<DayScheduleVM>
....
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <table>
        ....
        <tbody>
            @for(int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].Day)</td>
                    <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m[i].IsRequired)</td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.TextboxFor(m => m[i].StartTime)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m[i].StartTime)
                    </td>
                    .... // ditto for `EndTime` and `Interval`
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" ... />
}
```